# Neo4j: property or node for language?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but anyway.

My problem is, I don't know which was is smartest. My case is I have a (person) who talks a (language). But does it make more scene to make language a separate node, or a property of (person)?

This is both for creating and look-up.

**EDIT:** Size of the db don't matter.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your use-case, what kinds of queries do you want to run.

In most cases using a property for language is a sane choice, only when language is an inherent important aspect of your domain then I'd probably model it as node.